# Regex for texts NOT enclosed in angled bracket - python

Tags: python, regex, string, brackets

I need to get the texts that are not enclosed in angled brackets.

my input looks like this:

```
> whatever something<X="Y" zzz="abc">this is a foo bar <this is a
> < whatever>and i ><only want this
```

and the desired output is:

```
> whatever something
this is a foo bar <this is a
> 
and i ><only want this
```

I've tried first detecting the things inside the brackets then remove them. But seems like i'm matching the attributes inside the `<>` instead of the whole `<...>`. How do i achieve the desired output?

```
import re
x = """whatever something<X="Y" zzz="abc">this is a foo bar <this is a\n< whatever>and i ><only want this"""
re.findall("<([^>]*)>", x.strip())
['X="Y" zzz="abc"', 'this is a\n    ', ' whatever']
```

Comment: Why isn't `<this is a>` removed from the output ?

Comment: i dont use python but this `<.+?>` matches everything you need to replace in your sample data. will this do? Sniffer has a point though. i just thought 'remove what you don't want'

Comment: because it is `<this isa\n` and then `>` =). i assume that no tags will have a `\n` in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the parenthesis just inside the quotes (and remove the parenthesis you already have) in the regex pattern to grab all of the text between `<...>` including the brackets themselves. You also need to exclude the `\n` characters to achieve the output you want.

```
import re
x =  """whatever something<X="Y" zzz="abc">this is a foo bar <this is a\n\
        < whatever>and i ><only want this"""
y = re.findall("(<[^>\n]*>)",x.strip())
z = x[:]
for i in y:
    z = z.replace(i,'\n')
print(z)
whatever something
this is a foo bar <this is a

and i ><only want this
```

The parentheses indicate which text you want to group when the `findall` finds a match.

Comment: ah it misses the `>` on the third output line?

Comment: I don't understand your question here... the output of this bit is exactly the desired output you put in the original question... Do you want the `>` after the `i ` or not?

Comment: There is a `> ` before the `< whatever>` and `an i><only want this`, so i also wanted to catch that `> `. But no worries, i've caught it too ;}